# How to view and test a variable in each instance of an object type?

Tags: c#, object, console, iteration, instance

I'm trying to make a sort of "Fake OS" that looks like its own terminal but is really a C# Console Application (For fun). I need a way to look at each User instance (User is a class) and test to see if the Username and Password match. I thought of having a pointer array where each element points to a different user, then iterating through that Array, but I keep getting an error. I have all classes in my program "unsafe". (i.e unsafe class User {}) Here's the Error:

Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('FakeTerminal.User')

Also, Here's where I'm getting the error:

```
User root = new User("ROOT", "password");
User*[] UserList;
UserList[0] = *(&root)
```

Oh, and just in case, my User class simply has two string variables: UserName and Password. Both are initialized in a parameterized constructor.

I get that instances themselves are pointers in a way, but I need a way to check *each instance*.

Any help please?

EDIT: someone suggested using references, if that's a better way, how would I do that?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use pointers? What's wrong with just using references?

Comment: I'm trying to make a login process, where it checks all User instances for both a matching username and password. Well, how would you use references here? (I'm not very familiar with references)

Comment: Any time you declare a variable of `class` type, it is by default a reference; classes are referred to as "reference types" for that reason. So your code `User root = new User("ROOT", "password");` allocates a new `User` object, and then stores a *reference* to it in the `root` variable. So the next two lines should just be `User[] userList = new User[8];` (allocate an array of `User` *references*,) and then `userList[0] = root;` (assign the reference to the root user to the first element of the array.

Comment: These are the most basic building blocks of C#, so investing time in a tutorial would probably be helpful. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just do something like this is your pseudo application?

```
User root = new User("ROOT","password");
var userList = new List<User>();
userList.Add(root);
```

You can then add any number of objects of type User to your list.

To run through them, do something like this:

```
User currentUser;
//logic to get username/password for current user

foreach(User validUser in userList)
{
     //logic to determine login
}
//whatever invalid login logic you need
```

Looking at what you're trying to do though, I think a Dictionary may be better.  You would use your username as key, password as value, then in your Dictionary object perform a trygetvalue against the username then ensure the passwords match.

In any case, this answer should resolve your initial question.  I would recommend reading up on the Dictionary to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: **Thank you so much for the help! It works!** I actually didn't know how to use the List<>, the book I have on C# doesn't cover it.

Answer (score 0):

create List of users

```
List<User> userList = new List<User>();
```

you can add users like below

```
userList.Add(new User(){ UserName = "ROOT", Password = "password"});
```

You can iterate items by for loop or foreach loop.